# How to log data in multisim?

Tags: multisim

I am running a simulation in Multisim.  I am currently capturing data with the generic 4 channel oscilloscope component and manually saving the results to file after a short run.  I would like to let my simulation run for a long time, but after a period, the oscilloscope discards all of it's data and starts over.  I've increased the number of samples it will save in the simulation settings, but this only delays the problem.

How can I directly log voltage levels (or other data) to file in Multisim? Or alternatively, what is a better way to capture data from a long running simulation?

Comment: After additional, largely fruitless searching, the only solution I've found is to use LabView to create a custom instrument that will log the data to file.  One would think that there would be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

National Instruments has a [portal](https://decibel.ni.com/content/groups/multisim-custom-simulation-analyses-and-instruments-powered-by-labview) for sharing custom VIs. One of them, the [Waveform Recorder](https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-28161), logs input data to a variety of file types, specifically to solve the problem of saving data during long running simulations.

On a related note, National Instruments has a [tutorial](http://www.ni.com/tutorial/5635/en/) on creating custom VIs for integration with Multisim.